# Wireless chipset doesn't show up in ifconfig

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, atheros

i have an HP 15 with Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64bit install, Atheros chipset, i have ath9k installed, and kernel version 3.2.0-70-generic, i had this issue with version 3.2.0-24-generic but solved following a tutorial instructing the install of  backports
here is some info

```
wolf@wolf:~$ ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:d3:c1:6f:3a:67  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
          Interrupt:42 Base address:0x8000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1932 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1932 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:192105 (192.1 KB)  TX bytes:192105 (192.1 KB)
```

and

```
wolf@wolf:~$ lspci | grep "Network"
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

also

```
wolf@wolf:~$ sudo ifup wlan0
Ignoring unknown interface wlan0=wlan0.
```

any idea would be greatly appreciated
UPDATE : results of lspci -nn | grep 0280

```
wolf@wolf:~$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter [168c:0036] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your relatively new device 168c:0036 isn't covered in your relatively old 3.2.0-xx kernel. You can correct this by installing the wireless modules backported from kernel version 3.8. First, identify your kernel details:

```
uname -r
```

Your kernel will either be 3.2.0-xx-generic or -generic-pae. Obtain a temporary internet connection and open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic
```

Or:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-backports-modules-cw-3.8-precise-generic-pae
```

As needed. Reboot and your wireless should be working.

Comment: as for this pae thing, how can i figure it out, i mean is there any command that output my pae support?

Comment: As I said in my answer, please run: uname -r. Does the result mention pae?

Comment: `wolf@wolf:~$ uname -r  
3.2.0-70-generic`
no pae here, thank you i'll confirm after reboot

Comment: Thank you @chili555 it works perfectly, can i have a couple minutes of your time on chat please

Comment: i got chat to work @chili555